# python open webbrowser and get html

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now let me start off by saying that I know bs4, scrapy, selenium and so much more can do this but that isnt what I want for numerous reasons.

What I would like to do is open a webbrowser (chrome, ie, firefox) and extract the html from the page after loading the site in that web browser from what webbrowser.

```
import webbrowser
import time


class ScreenCapture:
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open(url)

    # get html from browser that is open
```

Comment: The [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module is only for displaying HTML (etc) in your browser, it doesn't allow you to extract anything.

Comment: As @PM2Ring mentioned `webbrowser` is a high level module simply dealing with displaying web pages on browsers and it's functionality is limited to that only. Can you explain why do you need to do this task using this module only?

Comment: the issue is one of the sites I am trying to go to will through a 456 at me using urlopen, scrapy, bs4 or selenium. But doesnt when I us the webbrowser open

Comment: Did you try requests too?